# SAS intnx quarter variation

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

sorry it is probably a very simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer to it.

Say, we want to create a table that contains 4 quarters back from the previous month:

```
%macro asd;

%let today = %sysfunc(today());

%let quarter_count_back = 4;

%let first_quarter = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&today.,-1));

proc sql;
create table quarters
(
Quarters num informat = date9. format = date9.
);
insert into quarters

%do i = 0 %to -&quarter_count_back.+1 %by -1;

values(%sysfunc(intnx(quarter,&first_quarter.,&i.)))

%end;
;
quit;


run;
%mend asd;
%asd;
run;
```

This code works just fine and creates a table, which starts from APR2016 and goes back in time by quarter. However, if I change the number in the 'first_quarter' line for -2, -3 etc... the code always starts from JAN2016 which just doesn't make any sense to me! For example:

```
%let first_quarter = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&today.,-2));
```

It seems logical that if I put this line in the code the table should start from MAR2016 and go back by quarter, but it does not, it starts from JAN2016.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at what the fourth parameter is for INTNX and the default behaviour. You want `'s'` or same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default alignment for the INTNX function is the beginning of the interval. If you want it to go back 3 months, that's different than quarters. You can adjust these by looking at the fourth parameter of the INTNX function which controls the alignment. Options are:

- Same
- Beginning
- End

If you want three months, try the MONTH.3 interval instead of quarter.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm

Comment: Thanks! Only the 'same' alignment worked, however. I am not sure, but why 'end' alignment didn't work? It seems logical to loop back by it... BTW isn't a quarter the same as 3 months?

Comment: From what I understand, Quarters are the specific intervals - Jan- Mar, whereas 3 months can be any 3 months Feb to Apr for example.